# Access root state from module getters in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have root state which contains auth data from nuxt/auth..

Inside store/modules/messages/ I have also state and getters etc..

Inside getters I need to get auth data from root state but I dont know how..

I tried adding rootState to index.js from module:

```
import state from './state'
import rootState from '../../state'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as getters from './getters'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  rootState,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}

export const avatar = (rootState) => rootState.auth.user.avatar
```

But this still returns module state..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a vuex module, a getter gets 4 arguments, namely local state, local getters, root state and root getters.

```
// messages/getters.js

export function avatar (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
  return rootState.auth.user.avatar
}
```

Comment: Yeah I found out that, so I need to add state, getters, rootState to get rootState or can I get only rootState?

Comment: It's always the third argument. Afaik only in actions you can just destructure the first argument. There's always the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) of course, but I hate that.